Django date input format seems not to be accepted
I put a DateField inside a ModelForm, which seems to work fine, if I add new entries to my database. Then I added a page, where I can edit one of those entries. Of course, I am passing the date of the desired entry to the HTML, but the date format is not set as expected.
# models.py

class SomeModel(models.Model):
    someDate = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100)

# forms.py

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    someDate = forms.DateField(input_formats=["%d.%m.%y"], label="Some Date")
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        widgets = {
            "someDate": forms.DateInput(format=("%d.%m.%y"))
        }

# views.py
def someModel_edit(request: HttpRequest, id: int):
    # ...

    query = SomeModel.objects.get(id=id)
    form = SomeForm(instance=query)

    args = {
        'form': form
    }
    return render(request, 'SomeHtml.html', args)

{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<h2>Edit Model</h2>

<form action="{% url 'someModel_edit' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" name="edit-someModel" value="Edit">
</form>

{% endblock %}

I expect the format of the date in the edit page to be as I configured in the forms.py file (e.g. 12.08.2024). Sadly it always looks like this:

And even worse, if I edit the description of the model entry and hit save, the software tells me, that I use the wrong date format.

I recommend you to read DateField in Django documentation.

The field always accepts strings in ISO 8601 formatted dates or
similar recognized by parse_datetime()

You will probably end up with creating localization which allows you to render as custom defined format. Check this.
Note: Localization may only allow you to render the field as in custom format. For the field itself (in model), you may define any recognized format.
